# How to highlight currently pressed button element in Angular 2 on click?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this line of code:

```
<button *ngFor="let group of groupsList" attr.data-index="{{ group.index }}" (click)="processGroups(group.index)">{{ group.title }}</button>
```

Is it possible to add class `clicked` to the currently clicked button? And the remove if other button clicked?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `ngFor`s `index` with `[class.xxx]` like this:

```
<button [class.clicked]="clickedButton == i" 
   *ngFor="let group of groupsList let i=index" 
   attr.data-index="{{ group.index }}" 
   (click)="clickedButton = i; processGroups(group.index)">
     {{ group.title }}</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! One more thing: is it possible somehow to reset `clickedButton` when other button is clicked? I have some sort of `reset` button so I want to reset all colors to default when it is clicked.

Comment: Just set `clickedButton` to `-1` or `null`. I haven't added it, but it would be a good idea to declare `clickedButton:number` in your components class.